# How to create request if int is null and take all

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How to make a right request without a lot of conditions.

If string can be null i can use `someString.Contains(null ?? string.Empty)`

and my request give all, but how if my int is null take all? i don`t wanna make too much if else

```
var students = _context.Students.Where(x =>
                            x.FacultetId == Facultet &&
                            x.Profession.Contains(model.Profession ?? string.Empty) &&
                            x.City.Contains(model.City ?? string.Empty) && 
                            x.Course == model.Course &&
                            x.Specialization.Contains(model.Specialization ?? string.Empty
                            )
                            ).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but how if my int is null take all" ?\

Comment: is your int field in the context nullable in the first place? If it's a nullable int then you can just do the same "??" trick.

Comment: `someString.Contains(null ?? string.Empty)` is equivalent to writing `someString.Contains(string.Empty)`. I don't think you fully understand what the null coalescing operator (`??`) does.

Comment: but i wanna take all if int null

Comment: in the method to get the value with null

Comment: x.Profession.Contains(model.Profession ?? string.Empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making so many conditions inside the query, do it outside:

```
var query = _context.Students.Where(x => x.FacultetId == Facultet);

// filter by profession if there is some value
if (!string.IsNullOrempty(model.Profession))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Profession.Contains(model.Profession));
}

// continue with the rest of the filters...

// and only then execute the query
var students = query.ToList();
```

Checking for a nullable `int` is the same.

Assuming `SomeValue` is

```
public int? SomeValue;
```

then:

```
if (model.SomeValue != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.SomeValue == model.SomeValue);
}
```

Comment: 1000 request in 1 second

Comment: @Adilbek How/why would that matter? It is *much* faster to perform an `if` in .NET than a `WHERE` in SQL

Comment: if it doesn’t matter then i will use your answer